# Cypress: How to create loop for fixture file with multiple arr

Tags: typescript, loops, cypress, fixtures, ddt

[Here is image from page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1hqi.png)

Hi all, I'm new here. How to create loop for fixture file with multiple arr in Cypress to check all the list?

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "email": "jsmith@gmail.com",
    "due": "50$",
    "webSite": "www"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Frank",
    "email": "fbach@yahoo.com",
    "due": "51$",
    "webSite": "www"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Jason",
    "email": "jdoe@hotmail.com",
    "due": "100$",
    "webSite": "www"
  }
]
```

```
cy.fixture('folderName/fileName.json').then(function (testdata) {
            this.testdata = testdata
    })

    it('DDT fixture file', function () {
        cy.get('name_selector').should('have.text', this.testdata.firstName);
        cy.get('email_selector').should('have.text', this.testdata.email);
        cy.get('due_selector').should('have.text', this.testdata.due);
        cy.get('website_selector').should('have.text', this.testdata.website);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach would be `Array.forEach()`

```js
cy.fixture('folderName/fileName.json').as('testdata')  // alias sets "this.testdata"

describe('All testdata' function() {

  this.testdata.forEach(item => {

    it('DDT fixture file for ' + item.firstName, () => {
      cy.get('name_selector').should('have.text', item.firstName);
      cy.get('email_selector').should('have.text', item.email);
      cy.get('due_selector').should('have.text', item.due);
      cy.get('website_selector').should('have.text', item.website);
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress comes bundled with lodash you can use [_.forEach()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach)

```js
const testData = require('cypress/fixture/folder/path')

Cypress._.forEach(testData, (data) => {
  it(`${data} test`, () => {
    cy.get('name_selector').should('have.text', data.firstName)
        cy.get('email_selector').should('have.text', data.email)
        cy.get('due_selector').should('have.text', data.due)
        cy.get('website_selector').should('have.text', data.website)
  }
})
```

Comment: Many thanks, do you have an idea how to create loop as I describe in comment next message?

Comment: Maybe _.find() would be better approach than looping. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for answer, but how create loop like:

1. Find "firstName": "John" on web (from fixture file)
2. Once find it continue assertion in this current row, rest of columns like email, due and website where is mentioned firstName?
3. Once all columns was checked in this row, start loop next data set.

Those approaches make search on whole page not in one row.

Really many thanks with each help.